# Trocar os valores dos atributos "name" dos inputs/selects html subsequentes?

Tags: html, jquery

Acontece que eu tenho a seguinte situação, no meu **HTML** possuo a estrutura dessa forma:

```
<div class="form-row mt-3">
   <select name="produto0" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('produtos') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}">
      @foreach($produtos as $p)
      <option value="{{$p->id}}">{{$p->nome}}</option>
      @endforeach
   </select>
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-sm text-white bg-info" id="adicionar">
   <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i> ADICIONAR NOVO PRODUTO</span>
</a>
```

E depois quando eu clico no botão que possui o `id="adicionar"` o código em **jQuery** clona e repete esse trecho logo abaixo, segue o código em **jQuery**:

```
$( "#adicionar" ).click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var original = $(this).closest(".form-row");
   var copia = original.clone(true, true);
   original.after(copia);      
});
```

Depois disso eu gostaria que o próximo trecho de código clonado, ou seja, igual, tenha o atributo `name="produto0"` diferente, por exemplo `name="produto1"`, como fazer isso usando o **jQuery**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depois de clonar o elemento, você conta quantos existem e altera o atributo `name` concatenando o valor:

```
$( "#adicionar" ).click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var original = $(this).closest(".form-row");
   var copia = original.clone(true, true);
   // conta quantos selects possuem name começando com "produto"
   var conta = $(".form-row select[name^='produto']").length;
   // busca o select no elemento clonado e altera o name
   copia.find("select").attr("name", "produto"+conta);
   original.after(copia);      
});
```

Comment: Acho que no teu cód. so faltou na parte que conta, o "0" ali no ```select[name^='produto']```, ou seja, assim: ```select[name^='produto0']```. Ocorreu tudo certo, obrigado. Se der edita ali onde te mostrei pra ficar exatamente igual ao cód. **HTML** que coloquei, vá que outras pessoas se percam nisso!

Comment: Não, não pode ter o 0. :D

Comment: O meu funcionou com o zero ali, ta vou ver direitinho! ;)

Comment: Pode funcionar tb, mas aí vc tem que alterar tb aqui colocando um zero: `.attr("name", "produto0"+conta);`

Comment: OK, perfeito, salvaste-me! :D